# Unable to return to 'User Profile' page after login

Tags: php, authentication

I have `login.php` page for the user to login their credentials. After the user logs in that is when the `doLogin.php` page will be displayed. In other words their user profile will be displayed. On the User Profile element, there is an edit button which leads them to `editProfile.php` page to edit their personal info. However when I clicked the back arrow on my tab to go to the User profile page back an error **"Confirm Form Resubmission"** was displayed. How do I counter this such that when the user wished to go back to the User Profile page, their details will be displayed?

This is my `doLogin.php`

```
session_start();
$msg = "";
//check whether session variable 'user_id' is set
//in other words, check whether the user is already logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$msg = "You are already logged in.<br/><a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
$msg = "<a href ='logout.php'>logout</a>";
} else { //user is not logged in
//check whether form input 'username' contains value
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    //retrieve form data
    $entered_username = $_POST['username'];
    $entered_password = $_POST['password'];
    //connect to database
    include ("dbfunctions.php");
    //match the username and password entered with database record
    $query = "SELECT *from role,user
              WHERE user_name='$entered_username' AND 
              PASSWORD = SHA1('$entered_password') AND user.role_id = role.role_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM user,country where user.country_id=country.country_id ORDER BY  `user`.`id` ASC ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM book";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $update = "UPDATE `user` SET last_login = NOW() WHERE user_name='$entered_username' ";
        $resultupdate = mysqli_query($link, $update);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email_address'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender_id'];
        $_SESSION['role_id'] = $row['role_type'];
        $_SESSION['lastlog'] = $row['last_login'];
        $msg1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $msg2 = "<b>Gender: </b> " . $_SESSION['gender'] . "<br/>";
        $msg3 = "<b>Email: </b>" . $_SESSION['email'] . "<br/>";
        $msg4 = "<b>Your last visit on this site: </b>" . $_SESSION['lastlog'];
        $msg .= "You are logged in as " . $_SESSION['role_id'] . "<br/>";
        $rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
    } else { //record not found
        $msg = "<p>Sorry, you must enter a valid username and password to log in.<a href='login.php'>Back</a></p>";
    }
}
```

and this is my `editProfile.php`

```
// include a php file that contains the common database connection codes
include ("dbfunctions.php");
session_start();
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$queryedit = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=$userID";
// execute the query
$resultedit = mysqli_query($link, $queryedit) or die(mysqli_error($link));
// fetch the execution result to an array
$rowedit = mysqli_fetch_array($resultedit);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"         href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Edit Profile & Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Sign Out</a>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>OBC <small>onlinebookclub</small></h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form method="post" action="doSearch.php">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title/Author/YearOfPublish">
                            </form>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Registration Form - START -->
    <div class="container" id="container1">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href='addbook.php'>Add/Edit Books</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Add/Edit Authors</a></li>
                <li><a href='editProfile.php'>Edit Profile & Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
                    <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- edit form column -->
            <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
                <h3>Personal info</h3>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowedit['user_name'] ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowedit['email_address'] ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rowedit['id'] ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        #container1 {
            background-color: #e2dada;
            opacity: 0.9;
            border-radius: 2em;
        }
        .centered-form {
            margin-top: -185px;
            margin-bottom: 120px;
        }
        .centered-form .panel {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 20px 20px 20px;
        }
        h2{
            color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you exactly doing when the user clicks on the edit button, do you post some datas?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection; you should read on [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 0):

**First Way**

One way of handling such errors is to redirect the page to itself.
i.e when the user logs in and when you show the `doLogin` page, i.e the user profile page, ry to use the `header()` function

```
 header('Location:doLogin.php');
```

**Second Way**

You can make an `AJAX` redirect using `jQuery` or something